# Let $f: X \subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$. Then, $f$ is uniformly continuous if, and only if, for every sequence...

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $f: X \subset \mathbb{R}^n\to $. Then, $f$ is uniformly continuous if, and only if, for every sequence, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$, then $d(f(x_n),f(y_n)) \to 0.$
Even more, if $f$ is uniformly continuous then for every $a \in \overline{X}$, the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exist.

I am thinking very hard about this problem. It seems that every moment I will solve it, but it never happens.

I imagine that my problem resides in does not understand well the meaning of uniform continuity, and principally, I am sure that I can not apply the definition to this case.

Please, I appreciate any elucidate solution with an explanation about where to use, and how to use uniform continuity and in what part to use.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Assume $f$ is uniformly continuous. Let $x_n,y_n\in X$ with $d(x_n, y_n)\to 0$.

   Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, there exists a $\delta > 0$ with
   $ d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon $
   for every $x,y\in X$ with $d(x,y) < \delta$.
   For this $\delta$ there exists a $N\ge 1$ with $d(x_n, y_n) < \delta$ for every $n\ge N$.
   Thus, for every $n\ge N$ it follows
   $d(f(x_n), f(y_n)) < \epsilon$.
2. Assume $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Then there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ there exists some $x,y\in X$ with $d(x,y) < \delta$ and $d(f(x), f(y)) \ge \epsilon$.
3. As you said that $Y$ is complete: Let $a\in \overline X$. Then, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ with $x_n\to a$. Now, show that $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Does the limit depend on the sequence $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: I am sorry, the real question remains on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we can assume that $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}^m$, that is complete....

Comment: So, $\overline{X}$ is the closure of $X$. Hint 1. I got it! Very good! But, how can I construct sequences for the hint 2. such that $d(f(x_n),f(y_n))$ does not converge to $0$ if we don't have the function... That was where I get stuck....

Comment: @user: I expanded the answer/hints.

Comment: @user211257, thank you! I will think about them. I am very grateful to you!

Comment: @user211257, I can't solve the point 2. For the point 3., if $x_n \to a$ then it is Cauchy. But since $f$ is uniformly continuous, $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy. I can show it as follows: $x_n \to a$ means that $d(x_n,x_m) \to 0,$ then by the preceding question, $d(f(x_n),f(x_m)) \to 0.$ But since $Y$ is complete it means that the sequence $f(x_n)$ has a limit! It does not depend on the sequence: Take $y_n \to a$, then $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$ since the space is Hausdorff, so $d(f(x_n),f(y_n)) \to 0...$

Comment: @user: Concerning item 2: For $\delta = 1/n$ there exist $x_n, y_n \in X$ with $d(x_n, y_n) < 1/n$ and $d(f(x_n), f(y_n))\ge \epsilon$...

Comment: @ser251247, I thought about it, I just did not find a way to justify this. But it is true.... Thank you! My solution for the point 3 is right? (I really appreciate your help!!! Thanks a lot!)

Comment: @user: looks good.